# Relativistic Bohmian Mechanics

Tags: special-relativity, bohmian-mechanics

Is there a relativistic interpretation of Bohmian Mechanics, akin to QFT for the Copenhagen Interpretation?

Comment: The phrase "akin to QFT for the Copenhagen interpretation" does not make sense.

Comment: There are at least eight distinct interpretations of the foundations of QM, AFAIK QFT does not eliminate or add support to any of them, but I think your question is useful if I can be corrected on this point.